# Rails 4 - devise not displaying authentication errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm in the process of building a rails 4 app and I've run into a snag.  When I go to the sign in page and enter the information correctly everything works

If I go to sign in but I don't input one of the required fields (name, email, etc) it will put up an error message saying 'Please review the problems below:' but the specific error messages, such as 'email can't be blank' do not show up.

The errors displayed properly before I added styling..

The code is here:
https://github.com/mikejames386/Black-Fret
I'm currently working off the devise branch.

This is the first time I've ever asked a question on stackoverflow so please let me know if there is any other info needed.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="form_container"><!-- start form_container -->
    <h1>New Artist</h1>
        <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <%= f.error_notification %>

            <h2>Artist or Band Name</h2>
            <div class="form_section">

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :name %>
                </div>
                <br class="clear_both"/>
            </div> <!-- end form_section -->

            <h2>Primary Contact</h2>
            <div class="form_section">

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :primary_first_name, 'First Name'%>
                    <%= f.text_field :primary_first_name %>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :primary_last_name, 'Last Name'%>
                    <%= f.text_field :primary_last_name %>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :email, 'Email'%>
                    <%= f.text_field :email %>
                </div>
                <br class="clear_both"/>
            </div> <!-- end form_section -->

            <h2>Password</h2>
            <div class="form_section">
                <div class="field"><%= f.label :password %>
                <%= f.password_field :password %></div>
                <div class="field"><%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
            </div>
            <br class="clear_both"/>
            </div>

            <h2>Members</h2>
            <div class="form_section">

                <p>member multi-add goes here</p>
            </div> <!-- end form_section -->


            <%= f.submit "Add Artist", :class =>'btn btn-custom' %>

        <% end %>

</div> <!-- end form_container -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors on `Devise` log-in page are added as flash messages.

In order to capture them, add following lines in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg %>
  <% end %>
```

As per Devise Documentation

> Remember that Devise uses flash messages to let users know if sign in
>   was successful or failed. Devise expects your application to call
>   flash[:notice] and flash[:alert] as appropriate. Do not print the
>   entire flash hash, print only specific keys. In some circumstances,
>   Devise adds a :timedout key to the flash hash, which is not meant for
>   display. Remove this key from the hash if you intend to print the
>   entire hash.

Answer (score 0):

I have Devise set up on rails 4 with my app and I actually have a Devise User model, a registration controller (which youdon't need) and a Devise views section. You may want to follow this tutorial https://github.com/plataformatec/devise, if you scroll down a bit you will see configuring views. The below will get put into your user model and the validatable is for validations on email and password which may be why the validations are not working properly just a thought. But I hope this tutorial gives you some guidance.

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

After you install Devise and add it to your Gemfile, you need to run the generator:

rails generate devise:install

After you install Devise and add it to your Gemfile, you need to run the generator:
The generator will install an initializer which describes ALL Devise's configuration options and you MUST take a look at it. When you are done, you are ready to add Devise to any of your models using the generator:

rails generate devise MODEL

Replace MODEL by the class name used for the applications users, it's frequently User but could also be Admin. This will create a model (if one does not exist) and configure it with default Devise modules. Next, you'll usually run rake db:migrate as the generator will have created a migration file (if your ORM supports them). This generator also configures your config/routes.rb file to point to the Devise controller.

Configuring views

We built Devise to help you quickly develop an application that uses authentication. However, we don't want to be in your way when you need to customize it.

Since Devise is an engine, all its views are packaged inside the gem. These views will help you get started, but after some time you may want to change them. If this is the case, you just need to invoke the following generator, and it will copy all views to your application:

rails generate devise:views